# Alnum + Spaces? Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to check for both alnum and spaces in a string? I know I can use regex for this, but I was wondering if there was a method to just check for both.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: you can strip the string with spaces if the length of string changes then there is a space then use the new string to check for alnum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test that string is all alphanumeric (alnum) with optional space(s):

```
my_string.replace(' ', '').isalnum()
```

Test that string is all alphanumeric (alnum) and has at least one space:

```
' ' in my_string and my_string.replace(' ', '').isalnum()
```

Test that string is all alphanumeric (anum) with optional whitespace(s) of any kind:

```
''.join(my_string.split()).isalnum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming alnum means alphanumeric, try this:

```
if stringToCheck.isAlnum() and stringToCheck.contains(“ “):
    #take action
```